# Show there are are no simple groups of order 1638

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I'm trying to use Sylow Theory to show there are no simple groups of order 1638. I got so far as to factor $1638 = 2*3^2*7*13$ and compute that we must have $n_2|819$ $n_3 \in \{1,7,3\}$ $n_7 \in \{1,78\}$ and $n_{13} \in \{1,14\}$. But from there none of the usual tricks seem to work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $n_{13}=14$. Then $G$ embeds as a transitive subgroup of $S_{14}$.
The point stabiliser $H$ has order $3^213$ and has a normal subgroup $K$ of order $13$.
But the normalizer of $K$ in $S_{13}$ has order $12\times 13$ which is not a multiple
of $3^213$.

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions on the details: $H \in  Sly_{13}$, right? How did you get the order of the  point stabilizer of H (sorry if its an obvious theorem/corollary I'm new at this)?   The existence of K is due to Cauchy's Theorem, correct?

Comment: Edit: That $|H|=3^213$ is by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, right?

Comment: $H$ is the normaliser of a Sylow $13$-subgroup.

Comment: Every group of order $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$ contains a subgroup of index $2$.